# Odoo/Openerp How to add schema in the xml files used?

Tags: xml, odoo

How can I refer to the relax rng files that exist in a odoo installation so that I can get recommendations from my IDE as to what are the valid properties of the xml tags used?

Answer (score 0):

In odoo use the RELEX NG

Exaple :

```xml
<element name="addressBook" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
  <zeroOrMore>
    <element name="card">
      <element name="name">
        <text/>
      </element>
      <element name="email">
        <text/>
      </element>
    </element>
  </zeroOrMore>
</element>
```

for more detail you can see : http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html#IDAHDYR

Comment: Odoo already provides some *.ng files. How can I refer to those files from within Eclipse so that I can get recommendations when editing an xml file?

Comment: yes you are right there is in /odoo 9.0/openerp/import_xml.rng this file is define all the scheme you can add your attribute and new tag in this file.

Comment: I do not want to add new tags. What I want is for any new xml files that I create to have them validated at compile time by eclipse and for the code recommendation to give me legal tag attributes.